# Handling internal server error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to add internal server error in json response in my rest api build using laravel. I have added the below line in app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof API\APIError)
        return \Response::json(['code' => '...', 'msg' => '...']);

     return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

I have wantedly given my db credentials wrong. When i give request using postman, its showing 500 error code at top but it doesn't show anything in json response. I am new to laravel.

[Server Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZvoj.png)

Comment: Most probably the exception you catching is not an instance of `APIError` because of that it does not return the json response and just rendering the normal 500 response, so you are getting like so

Comment: Any code or example to add it in json response?

Comment: `return \Response::json(['code' => '...', 'msg' => '...']);` try to remove the if condition then try if the response is returned properly.

Comment: No Luck after removing if condition

Comment: can you try setting the status code manually? `Response::json([...], 200)`;

Comment: Well i tried this return \Response::json(['code' => '...', 'msg' => '...'],500);
   Still the same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165356/discussion-between-shobi-p-p-and-farook).

Comment: Any suggestion for this?